# Did Trump help Puerto Rico actively?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, hillary-clinton

This picture states that Trump donated his own money to Puerto Rico and "sent" several types of aid to them actively.

Is this true?

[image]

The picture is a "top" thread on his Reddit page with 6000 likes 
https://www.reddit.com/r/The_Donald/comments/737b57/puerto_rico_comparison/

Comment: Hillary has no power to do any of those things, except make a donation. One might as well complain that your neighbor didn't send in the marines. Instead, you should focus on timelines; it took the Don near a week to even say anything, and only after being criticized the whole time for not doing so. Clinton reacted the same day without anyone asking her to.

Comment: @KevinFee "Hillary has no power to do any of those things, except make a donation.  Clinton reacted the same day without anyone asking her to."  So has she made a donation yet, or is a message < 140 characters all she has done?

Comment: The interesting point about this claim is that the people making it obviously think Hillary *should* be in a position to dispatch FEMA etc., which clearly means they think she should be President. Couldn't agree more.

Comment: I am instinctively skeptical of any statement that says Trump donated money, let alone his *own* money. He has a long history of making big pledges in public and then never actually paying up, and when he does it usually turns out to be money one of his charities collected -- IE, someone else's money that he's taking the credit for.

Comment: Completely skipping over the text in the image, the pictures that were used are already broadcasting the author's political leanings, in such a way that it calls the supposed objective nature of their assertions into question.

Comment: @Flater So does the fact that it's a thread found on r/The_Donald.

Answer (score 22):

The relevant claim here seems to be the donation. Regarding the other issues:

- Trump is president. Disaster relief is in his area of responsibility, while Clinton couldn't send FEMA to Puerto Rico if she wanted to.
- The [complaint](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/09/29/politics/president-donald-trump-puerto-rico-hurricane-politics/index.html) about Trump is that he acted [too little too late](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/p-fears-slow-u-s-relief-efforts-late-article-1.3528094), and only in reaction to intense criticism. Displaying this forced reaction as an achievement is at least misleading.

### Claim: Trump donated 1 million of his own money for Puerto Rico

There is no source for this claim, not even a source claiming that Trump claimed that he donated that money to Puerto Rico.

Instead, the claim seems to be a combination of two issues:

- The announcement by Trump to personally donate 1 million to various charities at the beginning of September in response to hurricane Harvey.
- The announcement at the end of September by the Trump inaugural committee to donate 3 million to the Red Cross, the Salvation Army, and the Samaritan's Purse.

It seems that the 1 million donation did [arrive](http://thehill.com/homenews/administration/350999-trump-makes-good-on-pledge-to-donate-to-harvey-relief) at various charities (although there is at least some [unclarity](https://thinkprogress.org/white-house-walks-back-trumps-promise-to-give-1-million-of-his-personal-money-to-harvey-victims-4691cf5e6dd6/) who donated it). As this donation was made before Puerto Rico was hit, it doesn't fit the claim.

[There are plans](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/27/us/politics/trump-inaugural-committee-donations-hurricanes.html?mcubz=1) by the Trump inaugural committee to donate $3 million. These donations are not specifically for Puerto Rico, but at least the timing fits. But this is of course not Trumps personal money, but instead donations he received.

One should be skeptical about claims of future donations or claims of personal donations by Trump, as there has been [a pattern](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/washington-posts-david-fahrenthold-wins-pulitzer-prize-for-dogged-reporting-of-trumps-philanthropy/2017/04/10/dd535d2e-1dfb-11e7-be2a-3a1fb24d4671_story.html) of Trump claiming to personally donate money, when either no donations had been made, or donations had been made by the Trump Foundation, not him personally.

Comment: "This case fits into a pattern of Trump claiming to personally donate money" - as you have noted, this is not a claim made by Trump himself (in this case). So it does _not_ fit the pattern of _Trump_ claiming to personally donate money, etc.

Comment: @ff524 I meant the mentioned 1 million donation, not the claim about Trump donating to Puerto Rico. Still, I reformulated to avoid confusion.

Comment: As for what the Clintons are doing: https://www.clintonfoundation.org/press-releases/former-us-presidents-one-america-appeal-expands-include-hurricane-recovery-puerto

Comment: You might as well change the last paragraph to include charitable donations from all politicians. Also this: https://www.whitehouse.gov/blog/2017/07/26/president-donald-j-trump-donate-salary-department-education

Comment: @daniel This question is about Trump, not other politicians. I am also not aware of all politicians having a history of bragging about personal donations which they didn't actually make.

Comment: @tim I accept that it's hairy to look into donations and abductions made by other politicians during disasters, so lets focus on why it's wrong to imply in your answer that Trump often claims to make donations and doesn't such as your link where he actually donated 1 million dollars after pledging to, or my link where he does donate his presidential salary after saying he would.

Comment: @tim, the way the emphasis is used in your answer, it looks like you are saying that the claim is true. please consider clarifying (either adding "claim:" infront of the boldened claim, or by boldening the "no source available" answer)